# AngularJS: How to print out duration time with format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use below code to print the time duration:

```
{{(endTime - startTime) * 1000 | date: 'H:mm:ss'}}
```

But I get the time of GMT +8

AngularJS has any way to print out the non-convert duaration,
Or I need to use this way to do this?

```
{{(endTime - startTime) % (60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60) | number: 0}}:
{{(endTime - startTime) % (60 * 60) / 60 | number: 0}}:
{{(endTime - startTime) % 60 | number: 0}}
```

Comment: What does `* 1000` do?

Comment: javascript use the time with millisecond, and my endTime & startTime variable is produced by PHP time() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `date` filter formats a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) (in milliseconds), so it doesn't work on durations.

You'll have to do manual formatting, like you suggest.

Answer (score 26):

In AngularJS 1.3 and up, there is optional ***timezone*** argument in ***date*** filter. The doc says If the timezone is not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/filter/date

Adding 'UTC' timezone will print the duration.

```
{{(endTime - startTime) | date: 'H:mm:ss': 'UTC'}}
```

Comment: Not sure why nobody upvoted that answer before, but it's brilliant and works perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: Not working for me in case of need to show days also. Using this solution adds 1 day cause "dd" starts on "01". Need to check if duration is >=1 in order to substract 1 day duration (24*60*60*1000). Now it works! Thanks for inspiration

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use moment.js library. There are many features in it that would be useful for application improvement.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](https://github.com/oshai/angular-duration-filter/tree/master) bower component
to format by duration.