# How to make difference between two time value and Date value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to make a app which is base on time differnce and date difference, and both date and time is input by the user,and the time format both cases in 24 hr.when i try to subtract these value it give wrong ans.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
Time1:<br><input type="text" pattern="([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}" ng-model="time1"><br>
<br>
Time2:<br><input type="text" pattern="([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}" ng-model="time2">
<p> Your Time is ans is{{time1-time2}} </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: sorry that was in html now the code has been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is using the input type *time* for html and format the calculation result as described in [AngularJS：How to print out duration time with format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422945/angularjs-how-to-print-out-duration-time-with-format) by Aung Khaing Oo.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
Time1:<br><input type="time" id="time1" name="time1" ng-model="time1" placeholder="HH:mm" required /><br>
<br>
Time2:<br><input type="time" id="time2" name="time2" ng-model="time2" placeholder="HH:mm" required />
<p>
time1:{{time1}}<br/>
time2:{{time2}}
</p>
<p> Your Time is ans is {{(time1-time2)| makePositive  | date: 'HH:mm': 'UTC'}} </p>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('makePositive', function() {
return function(num) { 
    if(num < 0) {
       todayDate = new Date(num);
       todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate()+1);
       num = todayDate;
    }
    return num; 
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update: I added a custom filter to solve the time1 < time2 problem. I took the solution from here: [Display absolute value angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148216/display-absolute-value-angularjs)**

**Update2: changed the filter by just adding one day if the difference between time1 and time2 is negative. Used [angularjs - calculate a date plus one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955253/angularjs-calculate-a-date-plus-one-day) as base for my adaption.**

Comment: Thank you for your response ,can you please suggest me how i can make this concept  ,if time1<time2, so it will add +1 in time1, i explain this in example suppose the time2 is 07:40 AM and time1 is 1:00 AM and now the time1 become 25 or 2:00 AM time1 become  26 but if the value is time1 is 07:41 is work as a normal .

Comment: Sorry it absolute value but my question is different please  check my qns.suppose user add time1 =6:00 AM and time2 =07:20AM in logic the 6:00 AM goes to as 30:00 and now the subtraction b/w  30:00 and 07:20.But if the value is greater than 07:20 it's subtract normal.